# How to Transfer a JSON value from a REST POST Response to a REST PUT Request in SOAPUI

Tags: json, rest, groovy

I have a REST service which I am testing with SoapUI. The first step in my TestSuite returns the  Response (Json): 'policyID'  then I need to  put this  in another request ( i.e, test step) to get the final response -  which is newly created policy number. I have written a code in groovy

```
import groovy.json.*

def response = context.expand('${CreateApplication#Response}')

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response) ---  Error line

log.info json.policyId

context.testCase2.setPropertyValue("id",json.policyID.toString())
```

I am getting error

```
Java.lang.ilegal.arguementexception :the JSON INPUT TEXT should should
neither be null nor empty
```

This error is coming at the line above marked as error, could you guys please help as I am not able to figure it out

Comment: Show the first test step response and request where the extracted value needs to be passed.

Comment: first step response - INFO:{"id":"xxxxxxx","issued":"1999-01-01","policyId":"1011","name":"test321" } request of second step -> { "id": "xxxxxxx", "issued": "1999-01-01", "policyId": "1011, "name":"test321"} - the policy id needs to be passed from step 1 response. Please note that all Responses (step 1 &2) are generated in script log tab of Soap ui

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly:

You can do below steps:

1. create a property transfer step.
2. Select source as ur first REST step response
3. Select Property Raw Response
4. Select Path Language as JsonPath
5. Use Jsonpath `$.id`.
6. In Target section use your testcase name
7. Create a test case level property `"id"`
8. Go to Property transfer step and select the same property name "id" in property section
9. save the project.
10. In the next step (REST) use id like below :

    `{ "id": "${#TestCase#id}", "issued": "1999-01-01", "policyId": "1011, "name":"test321"}`

Hope this is clear?

Comment: Thanks for response but i am not clear with Step no -5 onwards could you  elaborate in brief , Sorry new to REST /SOAP

Comment: Use Jsonpath : $.id  >> Where i need to define this. first step is POST and second Rest step is PUT

Comment: Update the comments